# TypeScript: ¿Interface para este objeto?

Tags: javascript, typescript

no estoy pudiendo armar una interface para este array:
Las primeras 2 propiedades que acá son COL6_SUM y COL11_SUM no siempre se denominan así, los nombres son variables.

```
COL6_SUM: {value: 4796088.75}
COL11_SUM: {value: 4796088.75}
childs: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
groupName: "CENTRAL"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: Array(4), groupName: 'COMP EN LINEA'}
2: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: Array(12), groupName: 'FACTURA E ANTICIPADA'}
3: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: Array(12), groupName: 'FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA'}
4: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: Array(1), groupName: 'SUCURSAL 9'}
```

Objetos childs:

```
childs: Array(10)
0:
COL6_SUM: {value: 205099.45}
COL11_SUM: {value: 205099.45}
childs: null
groupName: "01"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: null, groupName: '02'}
2: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: null, groupName: '03'}
3: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: null, groupName: '04'}
4: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: null, groupName: '05'}
5: {COL11_SUM: {…}, COL6_SUM: {…}, childs: null, groupName: '06'}
```

Intente con "tipos indexables" de typeScript pero estoy teniendo error:
Mi intento de interfaz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error: Property 'childs' of type 'rowsInterface[]' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ value: number; }'.ts(2411)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al usar un tipo indexable todas las propiedades del objeto deberán ser del mismo tipo. Eso puedes corregirlo haciendo que el tipo indexable sea una unión de tipos:

```
interface RowsInterface {
      [index: string]: { value: number } | string | RowsInterface[];
      groupName: string;
      childs: RowsInterface[];
    }
```

[Referencia](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

Comment: Buenísimo hermano, vi en la documentación que había que definir los tipos pero tenia un error en la sintaxis.
gracias.